# Moving one row to another based on value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to move data from one Google Sheet tab to another based on a value of one cell (a trigger cell). The "trigger" cell is the number of days until the due date of the specific task. That value is found using a simple code to count the difference in days.

I am having some issues getting the code to run. I have another sheet that does a similiar-ish thing and using the same code and it seems to work fine. Could anyone please give a fresh pair of eyes to see what stupid thing I have done now? I have tried to rewrite it and still have the same problem.

I have rewrote the code, copied and pasted from the internet, read line by line, I just can't seem to find the issue.

```
function moveToDue() {

  var UpToDate = "Up To Date";
  var Due = "Due";
  var triggerDue = "21";
  var triggerCol = 26;

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblahblahblah";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(UpToDate);
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

//Move to Due

  if (sheet.getName() == UpToDate && range.getColumn() == triggerCol && range.getValue() == triggerDue) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Due);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
      }
}
```

UpToData & Due are the different tab titles.

triggerDue is the number of days before the due date it needs to be triggered to move (in this case 21).

triggerCol is the column the trigger value is in.

Copy of sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-shzMIIlj247YFWY4Cc1bh6gW895lQWsjvc5gTi-fto/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When you say you're having issues, what is the actual problem? Also, what cell is the trigger cell? Does it ever change?

Comment: It's just not working. The rows aren't being moved. The trigger cell is in the Z column. It is a =DATEDIF formula to count the days between today and the end date of the specific program. At 21 days, the program info/row should be moved from "Up To Date" to "Due". So, when a cell in column Z has the value 21, then the row should be moved.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove all personal/sensitive data and share your sheet at all?

Comment: Sure thing: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-shzMIIlj247YFWY4Cc1bh6gW895lQWsjvc5gTi-fto/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Awesome thank you. On what event so you want this function to run?

Comment: It would be a timed event that goes twice daily. And thank you! I really appreciate you taking the extra time to look at the sheet. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Got it working! I'll update my answer now to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There are a few code issues including incorrect usage of `.getActiveCell()` and some `if` and `for` logic.*

#### Code fixes:

There are also a few things in your code that you could clean up - you don't need to make a check `if (sheet.getName() == UpToDate)` as you set this two lines before on `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(UpToDate);` without changing anything.

I've re-written a lot of the function to make it run more efficiently. Also, `.deleteRow()` seems to not always work if run alongside `moveTo()` in a loop, so I've added a function to clean up rows afterwards.

#### Code:

```js
function moveToDue() {
  var triggerDue = 21;
  var triggerCol = 26;
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblahblahblah";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var upToDate = ss.getSheetByName("Up To Date");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Due");
  var daysUntilEnd = upToDate.getRange(3, 26, upToDate.getLastRow() - 2).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < (upToDate.getLastRow() - 2); i++) {
    if (daysUntilEnd[i][0] <= triggerDue) {
      var targetLocation = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 26);
      var uTDRange = upToDate.getRange(i + 3, 1, 1, 26);

      uTDRange.moveTo(targetLocation);
    }    
  }
  deleteEmptyRows(upToDate);
}

function deleteEmptyRows(utds) {
  for (var i = 0; i < utds.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (utds.getRange('A' + (i + 1)).getValue() == "") {
      utds.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

  - [Method `.getActiveCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell)
  - [Method `.getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thank you a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Change these:

`var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblahblahblah";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);`

to:
`var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`

This is only going to work when a user opens a spreadsheet because they have to select a row. According to my tests, when you open a spreadsheet/sheet on the server the active cell is always "A1".